# cypress and select2 not triggering on select

Tags: testing, jquery-select2, cypress

I'm new to cypress and working my way through various examples to support testing of my app.

I've got a select box which uses `select2` - I can successfully select the item from the dropdown box but cypress is not then triggering the select event from which my code is running off.

How can I get Cypress to select the item and then trigger the select event?

Here's my test code:

```
cy.get('select[name=people] > option')
            .eq(3)
            .then(element => cy.get('select[name=people]').select(element.val(), {force:true}));
```

This succesfully selects the 3rd item in the drop down

I then have this code which takes actions based on the selection:

```
$('#people').on("select2:select", function (e) {
                var selectId = $(this).select2('data')[0].id;
                var castName = $(this).select2('data')[0].text;
                $('option:selected', this).prop('disabled', 'disabled');
                addCastTableRow(selectId, castName);
                initRemoveCastButton();
                $(this).select2();

            });
```

Any thoughts appreciated

Thank you

Comment: It will be very easy if you can add data attributes as part of the select box and the options.Or try something like cy.get('#people').click()  cy.get('#people').contains('option').click()

Comment: Also, can you add the error which you are getting?

Comment: I use something like cy.get('#select2-dummy-valuer').click()
    cy.get('.select2-results').contains('Dummy option').click()

Comment: Hi - that third option did the trick , Thank you. I've been trying to add the testing values dynamically  with db seeds so never knowing what the text would contain, simplified and added dummy values I now know exist and your method worked

Comment: This has been answered in another question https://stackoverflow.com/a/58261959/518130

Comment: @Ray added it as the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something that worked for me:

```
cy.get('#select2-dummy-valuer').click() 
cy.get('.select2-results').contains('foo').click()
```